# Eclipse Juno: Can't find fast view bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Version: Eclipse 4.2 Codename: Juno

I don't see a fast view bar in eclipse 4.2. I can't rightclick on a view and enable fast view. The fast view options under General -> Perspectives does nothing.

Was the fast view feature removed or am I missing something?

I've looked up at http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9b.htm , but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The single Fast view bar has been replaced by minimized stacks.  Now you simply drag your views into one stack and then minimize it.

Comment: Yeah. It would be so nice to drop some view on the minimalized stack. Its so uncomfortable to maximize it everytime I want to drag something on it.

Comment: I voted for it, and also added a comment about an other painful thing with these new stacks. Take a look, and vote :)

Comment: The juno docs seem to say that fast view is still there, but I can't find it anywhere. And this answer seems to state that it's been removed. Please could you clarify? TIA

Comment: The Juno docs might be wrong.  You can minimize a stack now, and open the individual views (similar to how fastviews worked) but there's no specific "fast view bar" that you can just send views to.

Comment: I used to like using FastView for my JUnit tests - it would pop up in large format, overlaid on top of the other views, rather being contained within an existing view. Is there any way to create an overlay view that you can min.max?

Comment: If you move the JUnit view to a new stack and minimize it, it will go to the trim.  If it is activated (by running tests) or you click on the JUnit icon in the trim, it will expand over the other views and you can re-size it as appropriate.

Comment: Kepler says the same thing, that Fast View is still there. So does Luna RC3. And the Preferences (General -> Perspectives) page still has a section for Fast View prefs. But org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow no longer has a getFastViewBar() method, so it would seem that Mr. Webster is correct. (He is one of the key developers on Eclipse Platform, so this should not come as a surprise.) I filed a bug. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436719

Comment: And how do you do that? What does that “stack” look like? Where do I find it.

Comment: Drag a couple of views ontop of each other, and then hit the minimize button on the right-hand side of the stack.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a request to get back the original behavior (from platform 3.x):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385105

Vote for it if you are equally interested.

Answer (score 2):

It is bit tricky read the documentation properly search for fast view bar in the eclipse documentation. in `General -> Perspective` area set the radio button to fast view and enable hide empty fast view bar. after opening the navigator minimize the navigator now reopen the navigator and click esc it should be working..

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the views previous located in the fast view?

Use the "Quick Access" search field to find the views.
(located in the top bar to the left of perspective views: Java, Debug etc.)

To view all, click spacebar.

Comment: What's the key combination to quickly access the Quick Access field?

Comment: @orluke use ctrl + 3 for quick access, it will show your previous choices, you can hit space to view all or begin typing :)

Answer (score 0):

Just open a New Window:   main menu | Window | New Window

The Perspective switching bar will be recovered for the new window and you can close the original window.

Comment: The question was about the Fast View Bar, not the Perspective Switching Bar.